# PHP cURL POST gives me error 403 while trying to contact STEAM Server

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to automate accepting trades on my STEAM account, I've been successfully able to login and everything is fine which gives me hope that I can contact the server remotely, also I kept the login cookies on using cURL cookie jar.
Here's my cURL code:

```
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$url = "https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/957#######/accept/";
$params = [
'sessionid' => "71824XXXXXXXXXXXX" ,
'tradeofferid' => ########,
'serverid' => #,
'partner' => ##############
];
$cookie_jar = 'C:\Windows\Temp\cooC0B3.tmp';
$session = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($session);
$response2 = curl_getinfo($session, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT );
print_r($response);
```

The user Agent is set to my current chrome browser which I'm using, and the session ID is the one stored in the cookieJAR.
Note that I've tried to inspect and edit the html script on real account login, I made a form to send the previous parameters by input field `Method="POST" action="<previous accept trade url>"` and successfully accepted.